# Trouble Understanding C Basics

Tags: c, arrays, fault

I am attempting to get into C programming, and I am having problems with assigning and pulling data from C-arrays, (in this case, to and from C-style strings).

Please point out any faults you see here.

I am primarily a c++/python programmer, so please keep the explanations of memory usage and management as simple as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct AuthorInfo {
  char* firstName;
  char* lastName;
} AuthorInfo;

typedef struct BookEntry {
  char bookID;
  char* bookName;
  AuthorInfo author;
} BookEntry;

void assign_str(const char** from, char** to) {
  int size = sizeof(from)/sizeof(char);
  printf((char)size);
  printf('\n');
  for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
    (*to)[i] = (*from)[i];
  };
};

BookEntry BookEntry_(const int id, const char* bName, const char* aF, const char*aL, BookEntry* ret) {
  ret->bookID = id;
  ret->bookName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(bName));
  ret->author.firstName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(aF));
  ret->author.lastName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(aL));
  assign_str(bName, &ret->bookName);
  assign_str(aF, &ret->author.firstName);
  assign_str(aL, &ret->author.lastName);
}

void display_book(BookEntry* entry) {
  printf(entry->bookName);
  printf('\n');
  printf(entry->author.firstName);
  printf(' ');
  printf(entry->author.lastName);
  printf('\n');
};

int main(int argc, char** args) {
  BookEntry book;
  book.bookID = 0;
  assign_str("Tom Sawyer", &book.bookName);
  assign_str("Mark", &book.author.firstName);
  assign_str("Twain", &book.author.lastName);
  display_book(&book);
  return 0;
};
```

Compiling this code with `gcc goof.c -o goof -std=c11` results in :

```
goof.c: In function ‘assign_str’:
goof.c:16:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   printf((char)size);
          ^
In file included from goof.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
            ^
goof.c:16:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   printf((char)size);
   ^
goof.c:17:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   printf('\n');
          ^
In file included from goof.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
            ^
goof.c:17:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   printf('\n');
   ^
goof.c: In function ‘BookEntry_’:
goof.c:25:26: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   ret->bookName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(bName));
                          ^
goof.c:25:26: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
goof.c:25:26: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘malloc’
goof.c:28:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘assign_str’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   assign_str(bName, &ret->bookName);
              ^
goof.c:14:6: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 void assign_str(const char** from, char** to) {
      ^
goof.c:29:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘assign_str’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   assign_str(aF, &ret->author.firstName);
              ^
goof.c:14:6: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 void assign_str(const char** from, char** to) {
      ^
goof.c:30:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘assign_str’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   assign_str(aL, &ret->author.lastName);
              ^
goof.c:14:6: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 void assign_str(const char** from, char** to) {
      ^
goof.c: In function ‘display_book’:
goof.c:34:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   printf(entry->bookName);
   ^
goof.c:35:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   printf('\n');
          ^
In file included from goof.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
            ^
goof.c:35:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   printf('\n');
   ^
goof.c:36:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   printf(entry->author.firstName);
   ^
goof.c:37:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   printf(' ');
          ^
In file included from goof.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
            ^
goof.c:37:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   printf(' ');
   ^
goof.c:38:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   printf(entry->author.lastName);
   ^
goof.c:39:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   printf('\n');
          ^
In file included from goof.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
            ^
goof.c:39:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   printf('\n');
   ^
goof.c: In function ‘main’:
goof.c:45:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘assign_str’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   assign_str("Tom Sawyer", &book.bookName);
              ^
goof.c:14:6: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void assign_str(const char** from, char** to) {
      ^
goof.c:46:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘assign_str’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   assign_str("Mark", &book.author.firstName);
              ^
goof.c:14:6: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void assign_str(const char** from, char** to) {
      ^
goof.c:47:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘assign_str’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   assign_str("Twain", &book.author.lastName);
              ^
goof.c:14:6: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void assign_str(const char** from, char** to) {
      ^
```

And running the code causes bash to say:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Add one important inlcude: `#include <stdlib.h>`. Make sure to read the doc for `printf`. It works with format strings, e.g. printing a number is done this way: `printf("Value: %d\n", val);`. There are formats to patch in string arguments, single characters, numbers, ...

Comment: `int size = sizeof(from)/sizeof(char);` will not do as you want with function arguments. The first `sizeof` will give the size of the pointer which is the only thing that the function knows about `from`.

Comment: Your use of `printf` is altogether wrong, please RTM.

Comment: And there is no way that `sizeof(char) != 1`.

Comment: The error messages tell you exactly what you are doing wrong. If you want to program, in general , you need to use some combination of reading books and/or online documentation t be able to solve problems and learn about the language you are using.

Answer (score 5):

There's many errors in there and no array, only structs.

- first, you must include the stdlib library (`#include <stdlib.h>`)
- secondly, the printf function can't be used like that.
  This function need a string to know how to print the data ex:`printf("an int: %d",myInt);` or `printf("a string: %s",myString);`. Note the %d or %s they indicate where to put the data.
- thirdly I think you want this `void assign_str(const char* from, char** to)`